# Error "could not convert string to float" when setting user-defined heterogeneous distance metric for mixed-type dataset in sklearn.neighbors

Tags: scikit-learn, user-defined-functions, distance, metrics, nearest-neighbor

Hopefully someone can help me out with the following:

I have a mixed-type dataset that contains both numerical (dtypes: `int`, `float`, `bool`) and categorical (dtype: `categorical`) variables in Python. Now, I want to train a Nearest Neighbor algorithm on this dataset using the class `NearestNeighbors` from `sklearn.neighbors`. To handle the different datatypes, I want to initialize the `metric` parameter with a heterogeneous distance metric. The `sklearn.neighbors` description states that "any metric from `scikit-learn` or `scipy.spatial.distance` can be used" to define this parameter. Because (as far as I know) these do not include a heterogeneous distance metric, I decided to use [`distython`](https://github.com/KacperKubara/distython/tree/master): a user-defined distance metric class that can compute heterogeneous distances for datasets with both numerical & categorical variables.

My code is the following:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from distython import HEOM

X_train # dataset with numerical & categorical variables
catIndices # column indices of categorical variables

# initialize heterogenous distance metric
heom_metric = HEOM(X_train, catIndices)
    
# Construct & train nearest neighbor algorithm
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric = heom_metric.heom)
neigh.fit(X_train)
```

However, I get the following error:

```py
Cell In[17], line 12
     11 neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, metric = heom_metric.heom)
---> 12 neigh.fit(X_train)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1152, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1145     estimator._validate_params()
   1147 with config_context(
   1148     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1149         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1150     )
   1151 ):
-> 1152     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_unsupervised.py:175, in NearestNeighbors.fit(self, X, y)
    154 @_fit_context(
    155     # NearestNeighbors.metric is not validated yet
    156     prefer_skip_nested_validation=False
    157 )
    158 def fit(self, X, y=None):
    159     """Fit the nearest neighbors estimator from the training dataset.
    160 
    161     Parameters
   (...)
    173         The fitted nearest neighbors estimator.
    174     """
--> 175     return self._fit(X)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py:498, in NeighborsBase._fit(self, X, y)
    496 else:
    497     if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree, NeighborsBase)):
--> 498         X = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse="csr", order="C")
    500 self._check_algorithm_metric()
    501 if self.metric_params is None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:605, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    603         out = X, y
    604 elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 605     out = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
    606 elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:
    607     out = _check_y(y, **check_params)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:915, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    913         array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    914     else:
--> 915         array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    916 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    917     raise ValueError(
    918         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    919     ) from complex_warning

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py:380, in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    378     array = numpy.array(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    379 else:
--> 380     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    382 # At this point array is a NumPy ndarray. We convert it to an array
    383 # container that is consistent with the input's namespace.
    384 return xp.asarray(array)
**ValueError: could not convert string to float: [element from categorical column]**
```

I understand that the `fit()` method from the `NearestNeighbors` class does not handle categorical object, because the kNN algorithm can not compute distances between `string` elements (obviously). However, I don't understand why this error is also given in my situation where I explicitly state a distance metric that can have a combination of numericals & categoricals as input and gives a single numerical distance value as output.

My hypothesis is that my user-defined distance metric for some reason is not properly 'recognized' by the `NearestNeighbors` class as being heterogeneous, and therefore the `fit()` already produces this `ValueError` before it even gets the chance to calculate the distances. The weird thing is that this error does not occur in the example supplied on the [Github page of the user-defined distance metric](https://towardsdatascience.com/distython-5de10f342c93).

My question is: how do I fix this issue and make sure that my `NearestNeighbors` class properly accepts my user-defined distance metric?

Thanks in advance.